# counting bits (1s) in an 8 bit number

Tags: assembly, counting, 8051

so in one part of my program which is in assembly language, i have to create a random 8 bit number that only has 3 ones in it... so i have created the 8 bit random number and im having trouble figuring out how to figure out if it has 3 ones so that if it doesnt i can create another one and check again. until it only has 3. So far i havent found anything useful online except for "hamming weight". But since i am not familiar with assembly language i cant figure out how to code it. 
this is what i have so far based on notes from class

```
rand8:  mov a, rand8reg ;puts the 1 bit of memory in a
    jnz rand8b      ;if it is 0 it will jump to the next loop
    cpl a           ;takes compliment of the number
    mov rand8reg, a
rand8b: anl a, #10111000b
    mov c, p
    mov a, rand8reg
    rlc a
    mov rand8reg, a

    mov r0, #30h
cloop2: mov a, @r0
    mov r2, #8
cloop1: rlc a
    jnc nocy
    inc 20h

nocy:   djnz r2, cloop1
    inc r0
    cjne r0,#40h,cloop2
    ljmp randloop
```

Comment: Have you considered bit shifting?

Comment: A better way to solve this problem is to generate only the numbers you want (via a lookup table, for example). Or generate three numbers from 0-7 and set those bits. Don't just generate and test.

Comment: @BethCrane i believe that is what i am attempting to do with the rlc (rotate) in my cloop1

Answer (score 0):

A way to solve this: Look at each bit of the number and xor it with 0 and add the result to a counter: if the value is != 3, try again.

[This](http://icfun.blogspot.com/2009/04/algorithm-bitwise-operation-to-convert.html) gives an idea of how this can be done, XOR isn't the only way to do it of course and you would increment a counter instead of printing to the screen. This is also horribly inefficient.

Comment: oh i see. how would i go through each bit of a number?

Comment: Edited the response, the link should help you out. Have a variable with a single 1 in it. Rotate it one step each time and do a bitwise operation. If the resulting number is zero you know what that the space lining up with the 1 was and can then act based on that.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it in C:

```
int main() { 
int v = 3; // count the number o ...
int c = 0; // c accumulates th ...

while (v) 
{ 
    c += v & 1; 
      v >>= 1; 
} 
}
```

This produces assembly code like this:

```
main:
   PUSH %BP
   MOV  %SP, %BP
@main_body:
   SUB  %SP, $4, %SP
   MOV  $3, -4(%BP)
   SUB  %SP, $4, %SP
   MOV  $0, -8(%BP)
@while0:
   CMP  -4(%BP), 0
   JEQ  @false0
@true0:
   AND  -4(%BP), $1, %0
   ADD  -8(%BP), %0, %0
   MOV  %0, -8(%BP)
   SHR  -4(%BP), $1, %0
   MOV  %0, -4(%BP)
   JMP  @while0
@false0:
@exit0:
@main_exit:
   MOV  %BP, %SP
   POP  %BP
   RET
```

I used this website to help me write the assembly, it explains it very well:
http://ctoassembly.com/

Comment: It gives me this error while trying to access the website--->`Forbidden.
You don't have permission to access /cgi-bin/ on this server.`

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility without using a loop:

```
COUNT_1BITS:
; Calculate number of 1 bits in A
; Return number in A

XCH A,R0
PUSH ACC   ; Save old R0 value to stack
XRL ACC,A  ; Clear A
XCH A,R0   ; Fetch value and clear counter

RRC A      ; Move bit0 to C
XCH A,R0   ; Save A, fetch counter
ADDC A,#0  ; Count Bit 0
XCH A,R0   ; Save counter, fetch A

RRC A      ; Move bit1 to C
XCH A,R0   ; Save A, fetch counter
ADDC A,#0  ; Count Bit 1
XCH A,R0   ; Save counter, fetch A

RRC A      ; Move bit2 to C
XCH A,R0   ; Save A, fetch counter
ADDC A,#0  ; Count Bit 2
XCH A,R0   ; Save counter, fetch A

RRC A      ; Move bit3 to C
XCH A,R0   ; Save A, fetch counter
ADDC A,#0  ; Count Bit 3
XCH A,R0   ; Save counter, fetch A

RRC A      ; Move bit4 to C
XCH A,R0   ; Save A, fetch counter
ADDC A,#0  ; Count Bit 4
XCH A,R0   ; Save counter, fetch A

RRC A      ; Move bit5 to C
XCH A,R0   ; Save A, fetch counter
ADDC A,#0  ; Count Bit 5
XCH A,R0   ; Save counter, fetch A

RRC A      ; Move bit6 to C
XCH A,R0   ; Save A, fetch counter
ADDC A,#0  ; Count Bit 6
XCH A,R0   ; Save counter, fetch A

RRC A      ; Move bit7 to C
XCH A,R0   ; Save A, fetch counter
ADDC A,#0  ; Count Bit 7
XCH A,R0   ; Save counter, fetch A

POP ACC    ; Fetch old R0 value
XCH A,R0   ; Exchange A and R0

; Now the number of 1 bits is in A 
; and R0 has its previous value again

RET
```